# Create dictionaries from the lists

Tags: python

I have a list `"testlist"` that contains 4x sublists

```
[
[name1,ip1,mask1,group1],
[name2,ip2,mask2,group1],
[name3,ip3,mask3,group2],
[name4,ip4,mask4,group2]
]
```

I want to get following dictionary from the "testlist"

```
{group1:[name1,name2], group2:[name3,name4]}
```

I have this little piece of code here which is taking "group" elements from each sublist and then updates dictionary with taken elements as keys. I'm stuck with is how to fill the values of these keys ?

```
def test():
dic={}
testlist = [
            [name1,ip1,mask1,group1],
            [name2,ip2,mask2,group1], 
            [name3,ip3,mask3,group2],
            [name4,ip4,mask4,group2]
           ]
for each in testlist:
    dic.update{each[3]:[]}
```

Comment: Are the items in the sublists of  `testlist` variables or strings? If they are strings, they are expected to be within quotes.

Comment: is string group1 and group2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the items inside each sublist of `testlist` are string, try this :

```
dic = {i : [j[0] for j in testlist if i==j[3]] for i in set([k[3] for k in testlist])}
```

Here is the same code in details :

```
unique_fourth_items = []
for i in testlist:
    unique_fourth_items.append(i[3])
unique_fourth_items = set(unique_fourth_items)
dic = {}
# Check in testlist for each item of unique_fourth_items list
for i in unique_fourth_items:
    temp = []
    for j in testlist:
        if j[3] == i:
            temp.append(j[0])
    dic[i] = temp
```

Comment: Nice and elegant, however you don't need to cast the set into a list. However, it requires two passes over the original list and another pass over the set, while with a simple loop we can do it with one pass (I'll post an answer).

Comment: That worked like charm.. thank you Michael.. I will ask you few more questions please.. I'm just trying to get my head around that complex structure.. 
when I see such structure, for some reason I start reading from the end ... 
as I understand, the first step is to create a set of single list that contains 'element 3's of each sublist, by iterating the testlist.

Answer (score 0):

Using a 'traditional' loop over the list (assuming name1, ip1, etc. are defined somewhere):

```
def test():
    dic = {}
    testlist = [
        [name1, ip1, mask1, group1],
        [name2, ip2, mask2, group1],
        [name3, ip3, mask3, group2],
        [name4, ip4, mask4, group2]
    ]
    for each in testlist:
        if each[3] not in dic:
            dic[each[3]] = []

        dic[each[3]].append(each[0])

    return dic
```